# How to apply layout template change to many pages?

Tags: websphere-portal

I'm not sure whether this question really belongs on Stack Overflow or Server Fault. Anyway...

I have a custom layout template (layout.html file) in the WebDAV file store on WebSphere Portal 8. This template is used by many pages - I guess about 100 - and I need to make a change to the template and apply it to all those pages.

To date, the only way I've found to make any Portal page pick up changes to a layout template is to change that page to a different template then change it back to the modified original template. This is a ridiculous solution when many pages use the same template.

Is there any way to make a large number of portal pages pick up changes in a layout template that they're already using, without manually updating each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this link is what you're looking for.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+WebSphere+Portal+7+Product+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Task_refreshpagelayout_wp7&content=pdcontent

The documentation guides you on how to run a ConfigEngine task to refresh the layout of all pages using a specific layout.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks heaps. Somehow I failed to find that page with Google; must've used the wrong words.